# Add info bubble to Heremaps in Android not in Javascript

Tags: overlay, here-api, infobubble, bubble-popup

I wanted to add info bubble in heremaps sdk in android application not in Javascript.

i can get the trip summary but I wanted to show info bubble same has been asked here but answered for Javascript I want in Android
[Trip Duration Summary as a tip message before starting Route on Heremaps SDK in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901850/trip-duration-summary-as-a-tip-message-before-starting-route-on-heremaps-sdk-in)

Answer (score 0):

Map.InfoBubbleAdapter is the interface for implementing custom info bubbles for MapMarker objects.

Please refer following link for more information:

developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.InfoBubbleAdapter.html

Happy Coding..!!